# Stop Page Refreshing - Persist Page-Data After Page-Refresh

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code in my html file. I want to change an image after a time interval, it run successfully but when i refresh the page it run the initial page. what i want is the same image is loaded so on and so forth !!

Anybody can help me?

```
<head>
    <style>
        #wss {
            opacity: 0;
            webkit-transition:opacity 1.0s linear 0s;
            transition:opacity 1.0s linear 0s;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        var wss_i = 0;
        var wss_array = ['<img src="img/russia.jpg"> </img>', '<img src="img/germany.jpg"> </img>', '<img src="img/france.jpg"> </img>'];

        function wssNext() {
            wss_i++;
            wss_elem.style.opacity = 0;
            if (wss_i > (wss_array.length - 1)) {
                wss_i = 0;
            }

            setTimeout('wssSlide()', 1000);
        }

        function wssSlide() {
            wss_elem.innerHTML = wss_array[wss_i];
            wss_elem.style.opacity = 1;
            setTimeout('wssNext()', 9000);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
     <h1>My dog is <span id="wss"></span> </h1>

    <script>
        wss_elem = document.getElementById("wss");

        wssSlide();
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: That's how it works. The loop re-reiterates whenever the page is refreshed. Maybe cookies might work for you.

Comment: you will need to store which image the user is on in a persistent state, options: [`cookies`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie), [`localstorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage)

Comment: @abc123 can you show me the code how to implement it !!

Comment: @witherwind  can you show me any example ??.

Comment: @Sumn2u, SO is here to help you out, not to do something for you. Try Google, it will be a very big help. Start with something, and if you happen to be on a pinch, that's where I will try to do it.

Comment: Example provided, this uses Cookies...enjoy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/qRBhV/118/)

**Description:**

The below code uses cookies to persist your state across refreshes and across closing browser and reopening, if the user clears their cookies this will no longer be maintained or if the number of days exceeds your expires in days variable when creating the cookie.

---

**HTML**

```
<h1>My dog is <span id="wss"></span></h1>
```

**CSS**

```
#wss {
    opacity: 0;
    webkit-transition:opacity 1.0s linear 0s;
    transition:opacity 1.0s linear 0s;
}
```

**JS**

```
//Global Variables
var wss_i=0;
var wss_array= ['<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />','<img src="http://placehold.it/350x250" />','<img src="http://placehold.it/350x100" />'];

//Cookie stuff
//Gets the cookie by the name passed, returns null if there isn't a cookie yet
function getCookie(c_name) {
    var c_value = document.cookie;
    var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
    if (c_start == -1) {
        c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
    }
    if (c_start == -1) {
        c_value = null;
    } else {
        c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
        var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
        if (c_end == -1) {
            c_end = c_value.length;
        }
        c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start, c_end));
    }
    return c_value;
}

//Sets a cookie with the name with the value and an expiration number of days
function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
//End Cookie Code

//Your code
function wssSlide(){
    wss_elem.innerHTML = wss_array[wss_i];
    wss_elem.style.opacity = 1;
    setTimeout('wssNext()', 9000);
}

function wssNext() {
    wss_i++;
    wss_elem.style.opacity = 0;
    setCookie('image', wss_i, 365);
    if(wss_i > (wss_array.length - 1)) {
        wss_i = 0;
    }
    setTimeout('wssSlide()', 1000) ; 
}
//End Your Code

//On window.onload, this occurs when the page finishes loading
window.onload=function () {  
    //store your wss_elem into the global variable
    wss_elem = document.getElementById("wss");
    //if there is a cookie for this domain with name image get the value
    if(getCookie('image') != null) {
        //set global variable wss_i to our cookie value
        wss_i = getCookie('image');
    }

    //start the slide show
    wssSlide();
}
```